# How to make a scrollable listbox? tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, scrollbar

I want to create a listbox with an auto hiding scrollbar. I've been searching and found a class example; when I play around with it, the scrollbar doesn't stayed attached to the right side as expected.

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *


class AutoScrollbar(Scrollbar):
    # a scrollbar that hides itself if it's not needed.  only
    # works if you use the pack geometry manager.
    def set(self, lo, hi):
        if float(lo) <= 0.0 and float(hi) >= 1.0:
            self.pack_forget()
        else:
            if self.cget("orient") == HORIZONTAL:
                self.pack(fill=X)
            else:
                self.pack(fill=Y)
        Scrollbar.set(self, lo, hi)

    def grid(self, **kw):
        raise (TclError, "cannot use grid with this widget")

    def place(self, **kw):
        raise (TclError, "cannot use place with this widget")


class Window1(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.list_frame = Frame(self)
        self.list_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.my_scrollbar = AutoScrollbar(self.list_frame, orient=VERTICAL)

        self.box1 = Listbox(self.list_frame, bg='black', fg='white',
                            width=60,
                            selectforeground='black',
                            yscrollcommand=self.my_scrollbar.set,
                            selectmode=EXTENDED)

        self.my_scrollbar.config(command=self.box1.yview)
        self.my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y, pady=20)

        self.box1.pack(pady=20, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        for num in range(15):
            self.box1.insert(END, num)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Window1()
    w.mainloop()
```

This is the first view when I run the code:

[image]

When I expand the window the scrollbar disappears properly:
[image]

But when I minimize the window, the scrollbar appears back but in an incorrect place and a strange shape:
[image]

Comment: It is because you did not specify the `side` option of `pack()` on the scrollbar.  Also `pady` option will be lost when calling `pack()` inside `AutoScrollbar.set()`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I did specify the side option you're talking about. Here: self.my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y, pady=20). Or where do you mean?

Comment: Inside `AutoScrollbar.set()`, you called `pack()` without `side` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you didn't specify `side` option of `pack()` inside `AutoScrollbar.set()`, so it is `TOP` by default.  Also you forgot to specify `side` in `self.box1.pack(...)`.

Below is the modified code to fix the issues:

```py
from tkinter import *


class AutoScrollbar(Scrollbar):
    # a scrollbar that hides itself if it's not needed.  only
    # works if you use the pack geometry manager.
    def set(self, lo, hi):
        if float(lo) <= 0.0 and float(hi) >= 1.0:
            self.pack_forget()
        else:
            if self.cget("orient") == HORIZONTAL:
                self.pack(fill=X, side=BOTTOM) # added side option
            else:
                self.pack(fill=Y, side=RIGHT)  # added side option
        super().set(lo, hi)

    def grid(self, **kw):
        raise (TclError, "cannot use grid with this widget")

    def place(self, **kw):
        raise (TclError, "cannot use place with this widget")


class Window1(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.list_frame = Frame(self, pady=20) # added pady=20
        self.list_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        self.my_scrollbar = AutoScrollbar(self.list_frame, orient=VERTICAL)

        self.box1 = Listbox(self.list_frame, bg='black', fg='white',
                            width=60,
                            selectforeground='black',
                            yscrollcommand=self.my_scrollbar.set,
                            selectmode=EXTENDED)

        self.my_scrollbar.config(command=self.box1.yview)
        self.my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y) # removed pady=20

        self.box1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1, side=LEFT) # added side=LEFT and removed pady=20

        for num in range(15):
            self.box1.insert(END, num)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Window1()
    w.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

@David 04. Your code is working. You cannot used less than 15. Unless you set geometry or resizable. should solved your problem.

Change this:

```
for num in range(15):
            self.box1.insert(END, num)
```

to:

```
for num in range(105):
            self.box1.insert(END, num)
```

You will get scrollable resizing.

Comment: It was acting up but thanks for your answer!